# How to configure kafka topics via Dapr?

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka, dapr

As per title, does anybody know how to configure kafka topics using dapr pubsub component? Specifically I would like to configure retention.ms topic property.

Current pubsub.yaml:

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: pubsub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.kafka
  version: v1
  metadata:
      # Kafka broker connection setting
    - name: brokers
      value: "kafka:9092"
    - name: authRequired
      value: "false"
    - name: initialOffset
      value: "oldest"
    - name: maxMessageBytes
      value: 8192
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your topics should be created ahead of time. For example, via a Kafka operator such as Strimzi or Bitnami

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah I get that, but I would like to do as much as possible with dapr, after all the point of pubsub component is to abstract away, as much as possible, underlying messaging tech. Thanks :)

Comment: Dapr itself just manages the connector. Not the infrastructure. You can put the topic yaml configs into the same file as `kind: KafkaTopic`, if your cluster has such a resource, though